# How to plot specific rows of qualitative data using matplotlib on python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, rows, dashboard

I have a large spreadsheet of data that for privacy reasons I cannot show, but there is a column called 'origin' where there are hundreds of rows for particular company names. For example: 500 rows of information has been input for 500 people working at "Sony". I want to be able to make graphs for the information gathered for each institution, but I am having trouble only plotting for specific rows. The goal is to make a dashboard for each institution.

A way of putting this would be:

```
fig = px.scatter(df, x='gender'['female], y='race', 
color='origin'['Sony'])
fig.update_traces(mode='markers+lines')
fig.show()
```

I want to focus on particular categories when plotting.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your question is much too general, without code and without test data (anyway, test data should be short, just large enough to show the issues).  You might take a look at [pandas' getting started tutorial](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/intro_tutorials/03_subset_data.html#how-do-i-filter-specific-rows-from-a-dataframe)

Comment: Matplotlib and pandas usually have no problems with [plotting categorical data](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html). So, unless you provide a more specific question containing your code and a sample input, I guess not much can be said about the solution to your problem.

Comment: The code you are showing is plotly code, do you need an answer in matplotlib or in plotly?